# Weierstrass theorem two variables

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, weierstrass-approximation

I know that the Weierstrass approximation theorem says the following: Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ a continuous function then for all $\varepsilon>0$ exists a polinomial function $p$ such that $\|f-p\|<\varepsilon$.

I was wondering if I have a non-empty compact convex subset $D$ in $\mathbb R^2$ and a continuous mapping $X:D\to D$ such that $X(x,y)=(f(x ,y),g(x,y))$. Then it is possible that there exist polynomials $p,q\in \mathbb R[x,y]$ such that $\|(f(x,y),g(x,y))-(p(x,y), q(x,y))\|<\varepsilon$ for all $(x,y)\in D$?

Could someone tell me if this version would be valid? Perhaps a bibliographical reference or a proof would be very helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, this is true. For a square, the proof of Weierstraß's theorem using Bernstein polynomials can quite easily be modified. Use Tietze's extension theorem to extend a given function on $D$ continuously to a square, approximate there and restrict the approximation. There are several different proofs like convolution (of a continuous extension of a function on $D$) with a $2$-dimensional Gaußian with very small variance and truncating the Taylor series of the convolution, or the abstract Stone-Weierstraß theorem.

Comment: Well the statement could be made even more general. See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem, the general Ston-Weierstrass theorem can be stated in the following setting. If $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a compact subset and $A\subset C(X)=\{f:X\to \mathbb{C},\,f\, continuous\}$ is an $*$-algebra that separates the points of $A$, then $A$ is dense in $C(A)$. In particular the set of polynomials is a $*$-subalgebra that separates the points i.e. any continous function on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be approximated by polynomials in the sup-norm.